# Keeping the UI updated while multiple threads work

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In my Window, I'm building 3 charts. They aren't loading particularly large sets of data, but it takes a fairly long time for the window to load with the data.

To address this, I'm multithreading it; each set of data is being loaded from its own thread:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread BasicAlertsThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BuildAlertsChart));
    Thread ResolvedAlertsThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BuildResolvedAlertsChart));
    Thread DetailedAlertsThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BuildAlertDetail));

    BasicAlertsThread.Start();
    ResolvedAlertsThread.Start();
    DetailedAlertsThread.Start();
}
```

Currently I have each thread updating a label's content when they're done to indicate that set of data is loaded:

```
lblDescription.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { lblDescription.Content += "Basic Report Chart loaded..."; });
```

Here's the method that one of the threads is executing as an example. Each thread does pretty much the same thing (with differences relevant to the data that's being queried).

```
private void BuildResolvedAlertsChart()
{
    List<AlertsViewModel> ChartData = new List<AlertsViewModel>();
    DateTime StartingDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);

    using (ApplicationDbContext Context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var Towers = Context.Towers.ToList();

        foreach (Tower Tower in Towers)
        {
            var AlertCount = Context.Alerts.Where(x => x.TowerId == Tower.Id && x.Date >= StartingDate && x.IsResolved == true).Count();
            if (AlertCount >= 1)
            {
                ChartData.Add(new AlertsViewModel { Alerts = AlertCount, Tower = Tower.Name });
            }
        }
    }

    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        ccResolvedAlerts.DataSource = ChartData;
        XYDiagram2D Diagram = new XYDiagram2D();
        ccResolvedAlerts.Diagram = Diagram;

        BarStackedSeries2D Series = new BarStackedSeries2D();
        Diagram.Series.Add(Series);

        Series.Brush = Brushes.ForestGreen;

        Series.DisplayName = "Resolved Alerts";
        foreach (AlertsViewModel Model in ChartData)
        {
            Series.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(Model.Tower, Model.Alerts));
        }

        lblDescription.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { lblDescription.Text += "Resolved Alerts Chart loaded..."; });
    }));
}
```

This isn't working quite so well though because the UI still remains pretty inactive until its time to update this message.

I know how to update the message while a single thread is working, but how would I go about doing it while all 3 threads are still busy?

I could use a callback the same way as I'd do with a single thread, but I'm worried about confusing the issue of what's loaded and what isn't if I use the callback from 3 different threads.

Additionally, with this approach I've noticed the UI isn't responding to things like dragging or scrolling until all of the data is loaded.

Comment: It really depends on what the non UI threads do. Do they access the UI thread. Do they fill a collection which is bound (and hence raising events to the UI) etc.

Comment: Basically they're just collecting information and presenting that in the charts. I've updated the question to show an example.

Comment: Well, the example code for the worker thread does 2 things - the first block retrieves data from db and runs on the worker thread. However the second part which binds the data to the chart (the whole block inside `Invoke`) is executing on the UI thread, and if it's slow ... Shortly, looks like the most of the code is executing synchronously on the UI thread, which explains the unresponsiveness.

Comment: If your charts are big - there is not much you can do about this, because all 3 threads populate charts on UI thread (via `Dispatcher.Invoke`). You can try something like splitting your work between multple `Dispatcher.Invoke(..., DispatcherPriority.Background)` to allow other operations with higher priority to be processed between your invokes, but I doubt that will help much.

Comment: By the way - are your charts interactive (user can some how interact with them) or not?

Comment: @Evk the charts are using [DevExpress Chart Controls](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraChartsChartControltopic) so the most interaction is a mouseover  that shows some stats about the data point. Beyond that, not interactive at all

Comment: Well that's still counts as interactive. There is a way to render non-interactive controls in separate UI thread, but for your charts it won't work I think (unless you are fine with losing interactivity).